# File Upload is not working with API Gateway Pattern

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I have implemented Spring security using- **The API Gateway Pattern**: `Angular JS`and `Spring Security` (referred [**Angular JS and Spring Security**](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv) successfully for my application).

In my application (divided into- Gateway + UI + Resource), I have created a `.pdf file` upload module in 'UI' application which is failing at `Gateway` application while it tries to redirect request to `Resource` application (even this file upload functionality was working fine before implementing this API Gateways pattern and Security).

The file upload javascript code from 'UI' application as below:

```
if(idProofFile.files.length == 0)
        {
            $scope.alerts = [
                             { type: 'danger', msg: 'No File(s) selected, please Browse and Select ID Proof File(s) first.' },
                             ];
            return;
        }
        else{

            // Upload user's files::
            //create form data to send via POST
            var formData = new FormData();

            for(var i=0; i< idProofFile.files.length; i++){
                if(idProofFile.files[i].size > 31457280) // check for each file size should not be more than 30 MB = 30*1024*1024 bytes
                {
                    $scope.alerts = [
                                     { type: 'danger', msg: 'The size of file: '+ idProofFile.files[i].name +' is more than 30 MB. Max limit of a file size is 30 MB.'}
                                     ];
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    var extension = idProofFile.files[i].name.substr(idProofFile.files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                    //alert(extension);

                    if (idProofFile.files[i].name.length > 0)
                    {
                        if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(extension) === -1) 
                        {
                            $scope.alerts = [
                                             { type: 'danger', msg: 'Only PDF files are allowed. Selected file:- '+ idProofFile.files[i].name +' is a .'+extension+' file.'}
                                             ];
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                formData.append("idProof",idProofFile.files[i]);
            }

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('POST', 'resource/upload_id_proof/' +$rootScope.loggedInUserPrimaryKeyId+'/'+$rootScope.loggedInUserId, false);
            request.send(formData);
```

The Spring security code fromm 'Gateway' application is as below:

```
        @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/update_new_user/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/message", "/home")
                //.antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/message", "/home", "/css", "/font-awesome/**", "/fonts", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/less", "/mail").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/css/**", "/font-awesome/**", "/fonts", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/less", "/mail").permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/ui/", "/ui/public/js/**", "/ui/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ui/public/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "SuperAdmin", "Owner", "Tenant")
                .antMatchers("/ui/private/projectadmin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
                .antMatchers("/ui/private/superadmin/**").hasAuthority("SuperAdmin")
                .antMatchers("/ui/private/owner/**").hasAuthority("Owner")
                .antMatchers("/ui/private/tenant/**").hasAuthority("Tenant")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                        .getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

The controller code from 'Resource' application:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload_id_proof/{userPrimaryKeyId}/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadIdProof(
        //@RequestParam(value = "infoClient") String infoClientString,
        @RequestParam(value = "idProof") MultipartFile[] idProofFiles,
        @PathVariable Long userPrimaryKeyId,
        @PathVariable String userId) {
```

The request is failing at 'Gateway' application and not forwarded to 'Resource' application. The exception at 'Gateway' is as below:

```
**Invalid CSRF token found for localhost:8080/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11**
```

Detailed logs:

```
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops.*']
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/configprops.*'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/']
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/configprops/'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@493c907: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@493c907: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@620: Username: 11; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: Owner; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: b6cd10df-a20e-49ae-9212-d32e7520db8f; Granted Authorities: Owner'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3439c41
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11
2016-04-29 10:00:05.802 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I have tried ignoring csrf by below code in Gateway app:

```
http.httpBasic().and()
.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/resource/upload_id_proof/**");
```

There is not any issue log this time but the request is not forwarded to controller in 'Resource' app and now the logs are something as below:

```
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/resource/upload_id_proof/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: ''
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/logout'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb6efb77: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@620: Username: 11; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: Owner; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 8902a97c-cd54-4c78-92e4-383270fd97c7; Granted Authorities: Owner'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/index.html'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/css/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/font-awesome/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/fonts'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/img/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/js/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/less'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/mail'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/ui/public/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/ui/private/projectadmin/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/ui/private/superadmin/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/ui/private/owner/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/ui/private/tenant/**'
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11; Attributes: [authenticated]
2016-04-29 10:56:32.165 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb6efb77: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@620: Username: 11; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: Owner; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 8902a97c-cd54-4c78-92e4-383270fd97c7; Granted Authorities: Owner
2016-04-29 10:56:32.166 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@442f6da3, returned: 1
2016-04-29 10:56:32.166 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-04-29 10:56:32.166 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-04-29 10:56:32.166 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-04-29 10:56:32.283 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-04-29 10:56:32.283 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-04-29 10:56:32.285 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-04-29 10:56:32.285 DEBUG 5912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Except this file upload functionality, all other modules are working fine in API Gateway pattern and I did not find much help on internet for this issue, please help me to proceed the request to the 'Resource' application.

Comment: I have added these logs by directly copying from Eclipse console, but these are not visible in proper format here :(

Comment: This looks that we now have all the necessary material to help you (I myself know nothing in your field, sorry).

Comment: Issue resolved and it is duplicated to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114646/file-upload-multipart-is-not-working-with-zuul-proxy