# File Upload (multipart) is not working with Zuul Proxy

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring security with Spring Boot and Angular JS.

In my application, every request is redirecting from a Gateway app to other apps using Zuul proxy. A file upload module is not working in this architecture.
The file upload javascript code is as below:

```
if(idProofFile.files.length == 0)
    {
        $scope.alerts = [
                         { type: 'danger', msg: 'No File(s) selected, please Browse and Select ID Proof File(s) first.' },
                         ];
        return;
    }
    else{

        // Upload user's files::
        //create form data to send via POST
        var formData = new FormData();

        for(var i=0; i< idProofFile.files.length; i++){
            if(idProofFile.files[i].size > 31457280) // check for each file size should not be more than 30 MB = 30*1024*1024 bytes
            {
                $scope.alerts = [
                                 { type: 'danger', msg: 'The size of file: '+ idProofFile.files[i].name +' is more than 30 MB. Max limit of a file size is 30 MB.'}
                                 ];
                return;
            }
            else{
                var extension = idProofFile.files[i].name.substr(idProofFile.files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
                //alert(extension);

                if (idProofFile.files[i].name.length > 0)
                {
                    if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(extension) === -1) 
                    {
                        $scope.alerts = [
                                         { type: 'danger', msg: 'Only PDF files are allowed. Selected file:- '+ idProofFile.files[i].name +' is a .'+extension+' file.'}
                                         ];
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            formData.append("idProof",idProofFile.files[i]);
        }

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('POST', 'resource/upload_id_proof/' +$rootScope.loggedInUserPrimaryKeyId+'/'+$rootScope.loggedInUserId, false);
        request.send(formData);
```

The Spring security code is as below:

```
  @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/update_new_user/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/message", "/home")
            //.antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/message", "/home", "/css", "/font-awesome/**", "/fonts", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/less", "/mail").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/css/**", "/font-awesome/**", "/fonts", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/less", "/mail").permitAll()
            //.antMatchers("/ui/", "/ui/public/js/**", "/ui/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ui/public/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "SuperAdmin", "Owner", "Tenant")
            .antMatchers("/ui/private/projectadmin/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
            .antMatchers("/ui/private/superadmin/**").hasAuthority("SuperAdmin")
            .antMatchers("/ui/private/owner/**").hasAuthority("Owner")
            .antMatchers("/ui/private/tenant/**").hasAuthority("Tenant")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

}

private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}
```

The controller code is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload_id_proof/{userPrimaryKeyId}/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadIdProof(
    //@RequestParam(value = "infoClient") String infoClientString,
    @RequestParam(value = "idProof") MultipartFile[] idProofFiles,
    @PathVariable Long userPrimaryKeyId,
    @PathVariable String userId) {
```

The request is failing at 'Gateway' application while redirecting the request to 'Resource' application. The exception at 'Gateway' app is as below:

```
**Invalid CSRF token found for localhost:8080/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11**
```

Detailed logs:

```
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops.'] 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/configprops.' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/'] 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher : Checking match of request : '/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11'; against '/configprops/' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher : No matches found 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.797 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@493c907: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@493c907: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@620: Username: 11; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: Owner; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: b6cd10df-a20e-49ae-9212-d32e7520db8f; Granted Authorities: Owner' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3439c41 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : /resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter' 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.800 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/resource/upload_id_proof/40/11 
2016-04-29 10:00:05.802 DEBUG 6020 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Please help me to proceed the request further to the controller successfully.

Comment: Looking at your JS code you aren't including the header (nor is there a cookie). Also have you read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipart) on how to do file upload with CSFR tokens? Also your code isn't really doing anything with angularjs it is bypassing its http service, so not sure why you even mention that in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @M. Deinum. Your clue has solved the issue. I have used AngularJS in all other modules in my application except this file upload. Now I have replaced it with Angular http service and this issue gone away. You made my day :)